# Spring Cloud Config Pattern Matching Not Working With SVN

Tags: java, spring, svn, spring-cloud-config

I'm having issues defining multiple svn based configuration repositories for my Spring Cloud Config Server. I have set up three config repositories. One for development, unit, and production. I've set the default to development (by setting spring.cloud.config.server.svn.uri = development repo uri). But, whenever I make GET requests to the Config Server's REST endpoints, I ALWAYS get the development config no matter which profile I request. See example below...

#### ex:

```
curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 'http://localhost:8888/my-service-accounts/unit'
```

#### results in:

```
{
   "name":"my-service-accounts",
   "profiles":[
      "unit"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":"750",
   "propertySources":[
      {
         "name":"http://PATH_TO_MY_SVN_SERVER/config-repo-development/trunk/my-service-accounts.yml",
         "source":{
            "server.port":8080,
            "hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds":3000
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

#### but I expected ...

```
{
   "name":"my-service-accounts",
   "profiles":[
      "unit"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":"750",
   "propertySources":[
      {
         "name":"http://PATH_TO_MY_SVN_SERVER/config-repo-unit/trunk/my-service-accounts.yml",
         "source":{
            "server.port":7777,
            "hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds":3000
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

- note the difference in the propertySources[0].name value. I expect this configuration to come from the unit repository but it's still coming from the development repository.

---

## My Config Server Configuration:

#### application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  profiles:
    include: subversion
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        svn:
          username: configserver
          password: ************
          uri: http://PATH_TO_MY_SVN_SERVER/config-repo-development
          repos:
            development:
              pattern:  ["*/development"]
              uri: http://PATH_TO_MY_SVN_SERVER/config-repo-development
            unit:
              pattern: ["*/unit"] 
              uri: http://PATH_TO_MY_SVN_SERVER/config-repo-unit
            production:
              pattern:
                - '*/production'
              uri: http://PATH_TO_MY_SVN_SERVER/config-repo-production

      discovery:
        enabled: true
  application:
    name: my-server-config
```

- **Note: my IDE (IntelliJ) is warning me that it cannot resolve the configuration property for spring.cloud.config.server.svn.repos.*.uri   ... but this is how the Spring Cloud Config documentation shows how to specify the repository path.**

#### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = "1.3.3.RELEASE"
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.5.RELEASE")
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.1.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: "base"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = project.ext.projectName
    version = project.ext.projectVersion
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.RC1" 
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server")
  compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka")
  compile("org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit")

  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

eclipse {
  classpath {
    containers.remove("org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER")
    containers "org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"
  }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = "2.12"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reorganizing the directory layout of my svn config repository and using the more flexible "searchPaths" property in order to achieve my desired functionality.

#### New SVN Repo Layout:

- /svn/config/trunk/dev/service-name.yml
- /svn/config/trunk/prod/service-name.yml
- /svn/config/trunk/unit/service-name.yml

Basically with this approach you define the configuration repository URI and then define a searchPaths property that does pattern matching on the incoming path to determine which directory to search for configuration.

#### New application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  profiles:
    include: subversion
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        svn:
          username: configserver
          password: ************
          uri: http://PATH_TO_MY_SVN_SERVER/svn/config
          searchPaths: ["{profile}"]
      discovery:
        enabled: true
  application:
    name: my-server-config
```

#### Access Config Server via HTTP Endpoint:

```
curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 'http://localhost:8888/my-service-name/unit'
```

The config server by default seems to match

```
svn_server/{application-name}/{pattern_defined_in_searchPaths}
```

Which in my case is :

```
svn_server/{application-name}/{profile}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity. I checked the code and could see that they don't have support for multiple SVN repository implementation. Its just for GIT.

In [AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java) they have 2 implementzation [JGitEnvironmentRepository](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/JGitEnvironmentRepository.java) and [SvnKitEnvironmentRepository](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/environment/SvnKitEnvironmentRepository.java). Now if u check who has extended this JGitEnvironmentRepository you would see that it has 2 implementations MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository and PatternMatchingJGitEnvironmentRepository. But there no Multi** implementation for SVN repository.